# Copiar dados de uma planilha para outra

Tags: microsoft-excel, excel-vba, macro

Estou com um problema em uma macro, estou tentando copiar dados de uma planilha e colar em outra, porém esta dando um erro na hora de fazer o inserte de uma nova linha (em amarelo).

[image: imagem do erro]

Planilhas:
[image: origem]

[image: destino]

Código:

```
Sub copiarDadosEntrePlanilhas()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Worksheets(2).Rows("2:2").Insert

'copia de Formulario para Apontamento
    Worksheets("Formulario").Range("B3").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Apontados").Range("A2")
    Worksheets("Formulario").Range("H3").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Apontados").Range("B2")
    Worksheets("Formulario").Range("B7").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Apontados").Range("C2")
    Worksheets("Formulario").Range("H7").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Apontados").Range("D2")
    Worksheets("Formulario").Range("N3").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Apontados").Range("E2")
    Worksheets("Formulario").Range("N7").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Apontados").Range("F2")
    Worksheets("Formulario").Range("N11").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Apontados").Range("G2")
    Worksheets("Formulario").Range("N14").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Apontados").Range("H2")
    Worksheets("Formulario").Range("B11").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Apontados").Range("I2")
    Worksheets("Formulario").Range("H11").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Apontados").Range("J2")
    Application.CutCopyMode = falso

'Mensagem de texto
    MsgBox "Registro concluído!", vbInformation, "Concluído"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

print do erro junto com as informações solicitadas 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sabe qual a mensagem de erro que mostra?

Comment: nn deu para mandar a imagem aqui

Comment: @danieltakeshi pronto já fiz a alteração

Comment: @danieltakeshi 3ª linha "Worksheets("Apontados").Rows("2:2").Insert"

Comment: @danieltakeshi todas as células são mescladas por exemplo as celular entre B3 ate F4 são mescladas , e sim a macro pertence a essa planilha mesmo.

Comment: FIZ O QUE VC FALOU E ND

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente trocar a instrução:

```
Application.CutCopyMode = Falso
```

por

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Wilson, para resposta tente dar uma resposta completa, quanto for tentativa use os comentários

Comment: BOM DIA    não consegui entender a sua recomendação

Answer (score 0):

Para seu código executar mais rápido, em vez de copiar e colar, você poderia fazer:

```
Worksheets("Apontados").cells("A2").value = worksheets("Formulario").cells("B3").value
```

e repetir essa sintaxe para as demais linhas do código.

Comment: Favor colocar recomendações como comentário e inserir como respostas somente que respondam a dúvida do  OP.

Comment: muito obrigado pela dica

Comment: porem eu nao estou mais trabalhando nesse setor

Comment: projeto esta parado